# Error reading data from textfile

Tags: java

I have an application that suppose to read data from the text file with student details (student.txt), such that I have a studentNo, StudentName, Marks etc. . .

Here is a sample of the data that's in the textfile :

```
20405587    "ZULU,B M"  65  67
20407388    "JUGGERNATH,N"  66  63
20408427    "KHATHI,P X"    60  60
20409821    "SINGH,T"   62  59
20410422    "NKOMO,N N" 58  60
```

I'm using a scanner to read from the file, here is my code so far. . .it gives me an error

```
try
{
   BufferedReader br = new   BufferedReader(new FileReader("student.txt"));
   String line = br.readLine();

   while (line!=null)
   {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);   
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");
        String dummystudent=scan.next();
        int studentNo= Integer.parseInt(dummystudent);
        String dummyname1 = scan.next();
        String dummyname2 = scan.next();
        String studentName = dummyname1+dummyname2;
        String dummytest1 = scan.next();
        int test1= Integer.parseInt(dummytest1);
        String dummytest2 = scan.next();
        int test2= Integer.parseInt(dummytest2);
        tad1.setText(tad1.getText()+"Student Number: " + studentNo + '\n' + "Student Name :" + studentName );

        line = br.readLine();
    } 
    br.close();
}
catch(Exception b)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,b.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: What error do you get and on which line?

Comment: whats the error? whats not working?

Comment: please, dont downgrade, let him fix 1st

Comment: Doesn't `Scanner` take a regexp, so there should be `\\s` instead of `" "`?

Comment: Don't catch Exception. Or at least, if you catch it, add b.printStackTrace() to the catch block and... miracle, you'll get a detailed report telling what the exception is, what its message is, and where it happens exactly in the source code. This is crucial information.

Comment: If you had just added `System.out.println(dummystudent)` (GUI's are overrated) and similar print statements for the other variables, you would've seen the problem quick enough.

Comment: @svz It does take a regular expression, but `" "` is a valid regex. Although [it should be `" +"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17930615/1711796), or `"\\s+"` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the delimiter `"? +"?`, the delimiter is a regex, and your string has multiple spaces to separate fields, you also need to take into account quotes around string fields. I'm yet to workout how to solve string fields with spaces.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)

---

Using Regex you should be able to do it using the below regex string, and select the subgroups 1-4, through a [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)

```
([0-9]{8}) +"([A-Z, ]+)" +([0-9]{2}) +([0-9]{2})
```

Comment: I did put the code scan.useDelimiter(" +") and if(scan.hasNext()), it only displays : StudentNo 20405587 Student Name :"ZULU,BM" , but not reading other lines or displaying the rest of the data in the text file. . . .reading only one line

Comment: I get an error saying Dangling meta character ? near index 0
?+
I think this has to do with delimiter and the spaces cause other students have two initials and others it's just only one, and I have to keep track of the entire name including the space on initials

Comment: How about you use regex to extract the parts? More exact imo

Answer (score 0):

You set the delimiter to **a single space**. This is the problem. `next` will return an empty string a few times because those lines of yours has more than one consecutive spaces.

Instead you want to say **one or more** spaces:

```
sc.useDelimiter(" +");
```

It's still not 100% since `"ZULU,B M"` has a space in the middle and `"JUGGERNATH,N"` doesn't, but I'll leave that to you to figure out. Maybe:

```
sc.useDelimiter("\"");
```

somewhere in the middle there.

The `+` has to do with regular expressions, see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more in general and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more Java-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing seems to be overkill.

Consider using Scanner to read the line and use StringUtils.split() to parse the line.

Here is some code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int index = 1; // Just for printing.

        for (String current : input)
        {
            String[] split1; // result: number, name, numbers
            String[] split2;
            String studentName1;
            String studentName2;
            String studentNumber;
            String testScore1;
            String testScore2;

            split1 = StringUtils.split(current, '"');

            studentNumber = StringUtils.trim(split1[0]);

            split2 = StringUtils.split(split1[1], ',');

            studentName1 = StringUtils.trim(split2[0]);
            studentName2 = StringUtils.trim(split2[1]);

            split2 = StringUtils.split(split1[2]); // default seperator is whitespace.

            testScore1 = StringUtils.trim(split2[0]);
            testScore2 = StringUtils.trim(split2[1]);

            System.out.println(
                index + ":" +
                " Number: " + ">" + studentNumber + "" + studentName1 + "" + studentName2 + "" + testScore1 + "" + testScore2 + "
```

Note: StringUtils is from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/)

Comment: Using Apache is overkill, since `String` already has `split` and `trim` functions.

Comment: String.split has some obnoxious edge cases that Apache's util gets around.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to end would to be go line by line.

```
Pattern filePatten = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d+)\\s+(\"[^\"]+\")\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s*");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Matcher matcher = filePattern.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
       String id = matcher.group(1);
       String name = matcher.group(2);

       //etc
    } else {
       //Warn : Fragile Regex
    }
}
```

Each group in the regex captures a part of the line. The second group captures the name with quotes. You might want to remove it.

Comment: Do I have to Import something to use "Pattern"?

Comment: @OupaMcCarthy `import java.util.regex.*;`